# how can I change dataframe value ab,ba to ab

Tags: python, pandas

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','d','a'],
                    'col2':['b','a','a','c','c'],
                     })
df3['col3']=df3['col1']+df3['col2']
```

and dataframe will be like this

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   a   b   ab
1   b   a   ba
2   c   a   ca
3   d   c   dc
4   a   c   ac
```

if ab=ba
I want ba, ca to ab, ac
like this

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   a   b   ab
1   b   a   ab
2   c   a   ac
3   d   c   dc
4   a   c   ac
```

thanks for your help
can I add question more?

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['banana','apple','pie','mango','cola'],
                    'col2':['apple','banana','mango','cola','mango'],
                     })
df3['col3']=df3['col1']+df3['col2']
```

result

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   banana  apple   bananaapple
1   apple   banana  applebanana
2   pie     mango   piemango
3   mango   cola    mangocola
4   cola    mango   colamango
```

change

```
col1    col2    col3
0   banana  apple   bananaapple
1   apple   banana  bananaapple
2   pie     mango   piemango
3   mango   cola    mangocola
4   cola    mango   mangocola
```

I want to do is filter if ab=ba change to ab

Comment: so if the item starts with `a` you want it sorted alphabetically, but if its not starting with `a` do nothing?

Comment: I want if value is like apple banana/ banana apple --> all of them apple banana

Comment: that's different from your quesiton, please update your example.

Comment: @김도영 is it important that `dc` remains in this order? or is `cd` fine?

Answer (score 2):

If it is important to keep the order of the first key, below is a working solution:

```
df3.join(df3.groupby(df3.apply(frozenset, axis=1)) # use a frozenset a key for uniqueness
            # below to craft a custom transform by using the first row per group
            .apply(lambda g: pd.Series([''.join(g.iloc[0])]*len(g),
                                       name='col3',
                                       index=g.index,
                                      ))
            .droplevel(0)
        )
```

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b   ab
1    b    a   ab
2    c    a   ca
3    d    c   dc
4    a    c   ca
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to generate col3 with `str.join` and `sorted` to ensure a consistent order of the letters:

```
df3['col3'] = df3.apply(lambda r: ''.join(sorted(r)), axis=1)
```

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b   ab
1    b    a   ab
2    c    a   ac
3    d    c   cd
4    a    c   ac
```

Comment: this is not his answer, `cd` not sorting and would be `dc`

Comment: @user1740577 I know, I asked a comment in the question, but I suspect this doesn't matter. If it does I'll update the answer but this requires more computing

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work, we can use `.stack`, `.sort_values()` and `.groupby`

```
import numpy as np
df3['col3'] = np.where(df3['col3'].str.contains('a'),
                       df3[['col1','col2']].stack().sort_values(
                                           ).groupby(level=0).agg(''.join),
                       df3['col3'])

print(df3)

 col1 col2 col3
0    a    b   ab
1    b    a   ab
2    c    a   ac
3    d    c   dc
4    a    c   ac
```

Comment: this hardcodes the value 'a', making it not a general solution ;)

Comment: @mozway that's true, but OP hasn't been clear

Answer (score -1):

How's this?

```
df3['col3'] = np.where(df3['col2']=='a', df3['col2']+df3['col1'], df3['col1']+df3['col2'])
```

Or maybe this:

```
df3['col3'] = [y+x if y == 'a' else x+y for x,y in zip(df3['col1'], df3['col2'])]
```

-=EDIT=-
If we're not bothered about the whole cd/dc issue try this:

```
df3['col3'] = np.where(df3['col2']<=df3['col1'], df3['col2']+df3['col1'], df3['col1']+df3['col2'])
```

or

```
df3['col3'] =[y+x if y <= x else x+y for x,y in zip(df3['col1'], df3['col2'])]
```

Comment: This is not generalizable to any pair ;)